# If $A^2$ has an eigenvalue $a$ then $A$ has an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

$A = n \times n$ matrix non-singular in the complex field ($n \geq 2$); 
$x$ is some non-zero vector in the complex field (of size $n$); 
$λ$ is a complex number;

Now, from:
$(A^2) x = λ^2 x$
is it possible to prove that
$A x = λ x$ ?

Can anyone help me, please?

### Many thanks.

First of all thanks for your answers: it's my first question, and I hope to improve next time ...

I'll try to make my question clearer: 
It should be true that: if A has λ as an eigenvalue, then A^2 has λ^2 as an eigenvalue.
I was wondering if the converse is true (and try to prove a more general statement, using induction if possible, that is:
"if A^n has an eigenvalue, A has an eigenvalue")

Comment: it's not true, but it is true for symetric matrices

Comment: Is your main question that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, or that it has the SAME eigenvectors ?

Comment: My question is simply the following one:

Comment: Does "A*A has an eigenvalue" imply "A has an eigenvalue"?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put it in a clear way ...

Comment: First of all thanks for your answers: it's the first time I posted a question, and I hope to improve next time ... It should be true that: if A has λ as an eigenvalue, then A^2 has λ^2 as an eigenvalue. I was wondering if the converse is true (and try to answer to another general question, using induction, that is: if A^n has an eigenvalue, A has an eigenvalue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your edit:

Suppose $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. Then

$\det(A^2-\lambda^2I)=0 \iff \det((A-\lambda I)(A+\lambda I))=0$

$\implies \det(A+\lambda I)=0 \ $, or, $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$

Hence either $\lambda$ or $- \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, as you wanted.

An analogous factorisation and proof can be constructed using the $n^{th}$ roots of $\lambda^n$ in the complex plane, similarly to how we factor the polynomial $x^n-1$ using the $n^{th}$ roots of unity. I leave this exercise to you.

Comment: I'm looking for a proof, without appealing to the factorisation theorem for polynomials (using the complex field), of the following statement (supposing it is true, of course): << "A^n has an eigenvalue" implies "A has an eigenvalue">>. Maybe this new question should be done in the right place

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\pmatrix{\sqrt2/2&\sqrt2/2\cr \sqrt2/2&-\sqrt2/2}$, $A^2=I$ so its eigenvalues are $1$ there exist elements in $R^2$ such that $A^2(x)=x$ and $A(x)$ is not an eigenvector.

In general, take any symmetry of the plan $B=\pmatrix{cos(\theta) & sin(\theta)\cr sin(\theta)& -cos(\theta)}$, if $x$ is not in one of the axis of the symmetry, you have $A^2(x)=x$, but $x$ is not an eigenvector.

Comment: So for you $-1$ is an eigenvalue of the identity ?

Comment: One of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $-1$ which is a "square root" of $+1$ in the complex plane

Comment: @Shakespeare okay, but note that for example with $x = (1,0)$, we have $A^2x = x$ even though $x$ fails to be an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: @Shakespeare nevertheless, $A$ qualifies as a counterexample to the claim in the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh right, I thought the question was saying something more intelligent than it is...

Comment: Nevertheless, the answer as written does not actually provide the counterexample

Comment: @TsemoAristide is there any reason you switched examples?

Comment: @Shakespeare to be sure, the body of the question disagrees with the title

Comment: I believe it won't point out any questions

Comment: @TsemoAristide any questions that were "pointed out" by the last matrix are pointed out by this one.  Also, it does have real eigenvalues, namely $1$ and $-1$.  Any matrix satisfying $A^2 = I$ can only have the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: I don't know exactly these questions, but here $A^2=I$ and you have elements in $R^2$ such that $A^2(x)=x$, but which are not eigenvectors AT ALL of $A$.